# Writing to a different location than the end of stdout

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I came across a question here earlier that made me wonder if it is possible to write to a different location than the end of the `stdout` fd in C. After some research into the issue I came up with no results and am still curious as to if it's possible.

Is it locked to a `FIFO` methodology? Can this be accomplished?

For example if I wanted to overwrite something I previously placed in `stdout` before flushing, could I enter it like any other `char` array to do it?

Comment: If `stdout` is directed to a terminal, then the best you can do is backspace on the current line by printing `'\b'` characters.

Comment: @user3386109 Is there no way to enter the buffer and treat it like any other char array?

Comment: On some operating systems, with some drivers, you might be able to mess with the output buffer, but you're just asking for trouble doing that.  The point is that you only control when data is put into the buffer. The data can be removed from the buffer and output to the physical device at any time.

Comment: @user3386109 could you share your knowledge of how/when you can do this in an answer? I couldn't find *any* information regarding this topic online and I think it'd be helpful to have out there.

Comment: Helpful to whom, and why? Note that I played around with this kind of stuff 25 years ago, so I understand the curiosity (if that's what this is about). The differences between now and then are a) driver complexity has increased b) security has improved. Which means a) you're more likely to break stuff and b) the OS won't let you even try.

Comment: @user3386109 More just curiosity for me. There's no language regarding it anywhere

Comment: If you wanna play, I suggest that you get a throw-away computer and download/install linux as the OS. That way you can modify the driver source code to do whatever you want. But just make sure it's a throw-away computer, because you'll probably lock it up and crash it in a way that requires you to format the hard drive and re-install the OS. Enjoy!

Comment: There's no language about it because it depends on what sort of file your standard output is connected to. If it's a disk file, then you can seek in the file and overwrite any part of what was written before (unless it was opened in append mode). If it's a pipe, terminal, or FIFO, then you can't successfully seek on the stream. You have to assume that once you've written a character to the stream, it can't be unwritten. There isn't a standard way to remove unflushed data from the stream buffer. The behaviour of other devices depends on the device. And the same is true of other file streams.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I am not aware of writing to a place other than the end of stdout, you can "simulate" doing so by removing characters with `\b` (for each character), outputting the wanted string, then rewriting the end of the content. This may not work in all terminals.

This doesn't answer your exact question, but it may achieve the underlying task you're wanting to accomplish. I use it for simple things such as progress monitors (outputting a percentage of completion).